# Prevent CSS being overwriten

Tags: html, css, jsp, stylesheet

I'm currently working in liferay portal and using the google charts framework within it. If you're not familiar with liferay it's basically just normal JSP's but obviously liferay has some built in stylesheets that they use.

I've come to this stage now where my own CSS is being overwritten by the liferay framework in some places. is there a way to prevent this from happening? This is particularly happening with Divs width that I'm setting. I set it to auto but at run time the div just completely shoots out the confines of the screen. For some divs my style sheet works, for some it doesn't. So that's how I kinda assumed that it's being overwritten some how.

If I do inline styling in the div e.g.

```
 <div style="bla bla bla">
```

would that perhaps prevent it being overwritten whereas say I referenced an outside CSS file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use the !important tag for ur css:
for example:

.bla bla bla 
{
 color:red !important 
}

Comment: its very strange that it doesnt work in ur case. using the !important tag is usually NOT recommended because of its "heavyness", but in ur case it should have been the best solution, unless the liferay framework is using the !important attribute too, and is loaded after ur css. if u have multiple !important tags on the same element, the last applied !important will be used. did using inline styles solve ur problem ?

Comment: Working with liferay is an absolute horror. I don't think they're using the !important attribute. I have 1 CSS file, and 2 JSPs. in those JSPs I have divs with the exact same class atributes that references the CSS file. At run time one works, but the other doesn't. I tried the inline styling and that didn't work either. Could it be that the initial width of the div is so crazy wide that the width:auto and overflow:auto just gets ignored?

Comment: attributes shouldnt be ignored, no matter what the old values where.. IMO, but i never had such problems, so no experience with that. sounds like u have fun tho :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inline styles will override rules from stylesheets. It would be better, however, to give the element an ID and use that to define its style than to use inline styles.

Though, if you need to do this to set the styles you want, you're probably doing something wrong.